# How to use wmctrl to pin application to all workspaces

Tags: wmctrl

I have a script, called at login, to move specific applications to their respective workspaces

I want to pin one application to all workspaces. According to [the *wmctrl* man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl),

> Desktop numbers start at 0. Use -1 to pin to all desktops.

However the command

```
wmctrl -i -r 0x03800003 -t -1
```

has no effect. Using positive integers pins the applications correctly.

(I have have obtained the window ID using *wmctrl -l*)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `-t -2` or `-t 4294967295`. Alternatively, try `xdotool search --name xyz set_desktop_for_window 4294967295` or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, "wmctrl -i -r 0x03800003 -t -1" worked for me, with the appropriate Id.

In my case...

1. start my desired window from the command line as a background process

> feh -x -g 624x168-0+0 --scale-down UA-keyboard.png &
> 2. get the id using wmctrl
> wmctrl -l | awk '$4 ~ /feh/ {print $1}'
> 0x02600001
> 3. wrap it into a oneliner for wmctrl to change to all workspaces
> wmctrl -i -r $(wmctrl -l | awk '$4 ~ /feh/ {print $1}') -t -1

Answer (score 0):

```
wmctrl -i -r <window-id> -t -2
```

worked for me (thanks to @harrymc), specifically with the Opera browser. This was part of a python script called at startup

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

time.sleep(30)

processes = {
    'Opera': -2,
    'Spotify': 1,
    'System Monitor': 3,
}
# Move processes to workspace
process_bytes = subprocess.check_output(['wmctrl', '-l'])
process_string = process_bytes.decode('utf-8')
window_data = process_string.split('\n')
for line in window_data:
    row = line.split(' ')
    window_id = row[0]
    description = ' '.join(row[4:])
    for process, workspace in processes.items():
        if process in description:
            # workspace is 0 based
            os.system(f'wmctrl -i -r {window_id} -t {workspace}')
            break
```